# Handle symfony2 form validation result in jquery

Tags: jquery, symfony

what I want to do is to send a form via jquery ajax to my symfony2-webapp. What happens on the server is that either the server responses the form with validation errors or a success message.

How can I handle this two different results in jquery?

Comment: Have you tried making your ajax call request a JSON content type? It may be a good idea to allow your controller to respond accordingly depending on the request format, and maybe also whether it's an XHR (ajax) or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your controller return a JSON array (use an empty template to print only the JSON and `json_encode` to produce a proper JSON). The Jquery load function takes a callback function as its third parameter that handles the AJAX response (once it's completed of course). With JSON returned from the server you can easily do anything you need - either display an ok message or any validation errors.

Comment: If you want your form to be handled with AJAX this looks like the best way. After all that's what AJAX is for - you don't have to reload the page ;) Of course if you want to return the whole form you can do that as well. Just call the jQuery `.load()` on a `div` containing the form and in the controller display the whole form (just the form without any layout) and this will work as well.

Comment: Thanks, now I try to do the following:

Answer (score 0):

> My problem now is that isValid is false, because a string field is not
>   long enough but the hasError returns false and the getErrors returns
>   array(). What could be the reason?

Add error_bubbling in every form field, heres an example:

```
...

$builder->add('name', 'type', array(
    ...
    'error_bubbling' => true
));
```